# Geometric interpretation of adjoint

Tags: reference-request, inner-products, adjoint-operators, change-of-basis, hermitian-matrices

Given the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = y^HMx, \, x,y\in\mathbb{C}^n$ where $y^H = \bar{y}^T$ is the conjugate transpose and $M^H=M$ positive definite, I find the adjoint $A^*$ of $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ using:

$$\langle Ax,y \rangle  = y^HMAx = y^H(A^*)^HMx = (A^*y)^HMx = \langle x, A^*y\rangle.$$

Then $MA = (A^*)^HM$, and thus $A^*=M^{-1}A^HM$ and $A=M^{-1}(A^*)^HM$. As far as I understand it, this can be interpreted as $A^H$ being defined wrt the canonical basis $\mathcal{E}=\{e_i :\, e_{ij}=\delta^i_j, \, i,j \in\{1,\ldots,n\}\}$, while its counterpart is really just $A^H$ defined wrt the basis formed by the columns of $M$: $\mathcal{B} = \{M_1, \ldots, M_n\}$. The same holds for $(A^*)^H$ and A. Could you recommend a reference discussing and illustrating the geometric interpretation more intuitively? Potentially with extension to infinite-dimensional vector spaces. I am guessing $M$ there would be some positive definite hermitian kernel.

How is the above reconciled with seeing $M$ as the metric tensor (i.e. $M_{ij} = \langle f_i, f_j \rangle$). I took the columns of $M$ to be the basis vectors, but what would be the geometric meaning of $f_i$ and $f_j$ in the above?

Comment: The definition of Adjoint has nothing to do with inner products in general. If $X$ is a vector space and $X^*$ is it's dual then for $x \in X, x^* \in X$ we define $\langle x, x^* \rangle = x^*(x)$. Now if $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces and $B(X,Y)$ is the set of bounded (continuous) linear maps from $X$ to $Y$ and $T \in B(X,Y)$ we define the adjoint of $T$ is a map $T^* : Y^* \to X^*$ defined by the equation: $\langle Tx, y^* \rangle = \langle x, T^*y^* \rangle$.

Comment: The way I interpret it is in terms of function composition. Since $\left(y^* \circ T\right)(x) = \langle Tx, y^* \rangle = \langle x, T^*y^* \rangle = (T^* \circ y^*)(x)$. So to me the adjoint of an operator is another operator which hash the property $y \circ T = T^* \circ y^*$ (i.e. you can take it out from the composition).